# mvn does not run test on appCenter

Tags: maven, visual-studio-app-center

I want to run my appium test on AppCenter and I have followed this documents

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/preparing-for-upload/appium#prerequisites

When I run appium script on appCenter it does not show any error but give me output as

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building run-test 1.0-SNAPSHOT

[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 

[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ run-test ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!

[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory src/main/resources

[INFO] 

[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ run-test ---

[INFO] No sources to compile

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ run-test ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ run-test ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.20:test (default-test) @ run-test ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running com.testscripts.RegressionTest
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.247 s - in com.testscripts.RegressionTest
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ run-test ---
[WARNING] JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!
[INFO] Building jar: target/run-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.20:integration-test (default) @ run-test ---
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent! The file encoding for reports output files should be provided by the POM property ${project.reporting.outputEncoding}.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.20:verify (default) @ run-test ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 8.623 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-08-06T07:39:58+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/214M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Cure.fit</groupId>
    <artifactId>Cure.fit</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Automation Test Project</name>
    <description>Automation Test Project</description>


    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>



    <build>

        <plugins>
                <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*Test.java</include>
            </includes>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.appcenter</groupId>
            <artifactId>appium-test-extension</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jcenter</id>
            <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>repl</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.javarepl</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javarepl</artifactId>
                    <version>428</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>java</executable>
                            <classpathScope>test</classpathScope>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>-Djansi.passthrough=true</argument>
                                <argument>-classpath</argument>
                                <classpath />
                                <argument>javarepl.Main</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>runRepl</id>
                                <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>exec</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <!-- Added for AppCenter/Test runs -->
        <profile>
            <id>prepare-for-upload</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.10</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/upload/dependency-jars/</outputDirectory>
                                    <useRepositoryLayout>true</useRepositoryLayout>
                                    <copyPom>true</copyPom>
                                    <addParentPoms>true</addParentPoms>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-help-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.2</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>generate-pom</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>effective-pom</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <output>${project.build.directory}/upload/pom.xml</output>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>copy-testclasses</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>testResources</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/upload/test-classes</outputDirectory>
                                    <resources>
                                        <resource>
                                            <directory>
                                                ${project.build.testOutputDirectory}
                                            </directory>
                                        </resource>
                                    </resources>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

    </profiles>
</project>
```

When I run the same project as `mvn test` I am able to run the test.

I have kept my JUnit testcase name as **RegressionTest.java** under src/test/java which extends Support.java which is also Junit file.

Could any one can help me what is the mistake I am doing.

Comment: Hi, I would thoroughly advise asking this in Intercom (the little widget in the bottom right of appcenter.ms).

What output do you get from `mvn -DskipTests -P prepare-for-upload package`?

Comment: Also worth double checking all of the requirements from the preparing docs:

No support for TestNG,
No support for Android 4.2 or prior,
Maven version must be atleast 3.3.9,
Support for Appium version 1.7.1 only,
JUnit 4.9 or newer,
Automating browsers or WebView context is not supported,
Tests that launch multiple apps or no apps are not currently supported. The test must launch precisely one app.

Comment: `mvn -DskipTests -P prepare-for-upload package` gives output as '[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS' Also, locally, my script works fine. even their sample also tried which is also works fine.

Comment: When execution complete it gives following error code `Error: Cannot run tests. Returning exit code 2.` Not sure what is the meaning of exit code 2. even not sure, it is app Center exit code or maven

Comment: Just looking at this with fresh eyes - I think your POM file might be missing an opening `<dependencies>` tag?

Comment: copied these files [link](https://github.com/King-of-Spades/AppCenter-Test-Samples/tree/master/Appium/Android/Maven/src/test/java/com/microsoft/altframeworktraining) and run successfully with own apk. Looks like object creation problem.  I will update once I succeed

Comment: Just to update the solution, `mvn -DskipTests -P prepare-for-upload package` packaging only src/test/java folder and my core framework code reside under src/main/java. Hence failing. Now, Moved the core framework under src/test/java and works fine.

Comment: Can you please share your folder structure if possible, I am also facing the same issue

Comment: Move all your code under `src/test/java` does not matter of folder structure.